# spring framework のfilter 設定

Tags: java, spring

SpringFrameworkでFilterを使用したいのですが設定がわからず困っています。
お手数ですが設定方法をご教示いただければと思います。

【やりたいこと】
・自作したFilter(authenticateFilter)の設定
・MyBatisのMapperを@Autowiredする

【試したこと】
・以下のDBやMyBatisの設定をroot-context.xmlを読み込めば Filter でもDB接続は可能でしたが、通常のサービスでロールバックができなくなってしまいました。
  datasource-context.xml
  mybatis-context.xml

【web.xml】

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>authenticateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>authenticateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

【root-context.xml】

```
<!-- filter -->
<bean id="authenticateFilter" class="com.hatak.filter.AuthenticateFilter"></bean>
```

【servlet-context.xml】

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
<import resource="./datasource-context.xml" />
<import resource="./mybatis-context.xml" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.hatak.mamafriends" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hatak.filter">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<!-- 例外のハンドラクラス  -->
<bean class="com.hatak.handler.GlobalExceptionResolver"/>
```

【AuthenticateFilter.java】

```
package com.hatak.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.hatak.mamafriends.constants.AppConstants;
import com.hatak.mamafriends.params.authenticate.AuthenticateParams;
import com.hatak.mamafriends.service.AuthenticateService;

/**
 * 認証フィルタクラス
 */
@Controller
public class AuthenticateFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * 認証サービス
     */
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticateService service;

    public AuthenticateService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(AuthenticateService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    /**
     * フィルタ処理
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        AuthenticateParams params = new AuthenticateParams();
        // TODO 認証情報の設定
        boolean res = service.authenticate(params);

        System.out.println(res);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * 終了処理
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpringとMybatisを組み合わせる場合は、mybatis-springプラグインを使うのが一番簡単で、かつ確実です。トランザクション管理については、特に以下の公式サイトを参照してください。

http://mybatis.github.io/spring/ja/transactions.html
mybatis-spring：トランザクション

コンテナ管理のトランザクションも、手動トランザクションの方法も記載されています。

---

なお、Spring管理のBeanでトランザクション管理をfilterで行った場合、そのままでは正しく動作できません。もっと詳しく言いますと、filterでSpringのAutowiredを使おうとすると動作しないのです。対応方法については、手前味噌ですが以下の記事を参考にしてください。

http://www.h3.dion.ne.jp/~alpha-pz/misc2821.html
[Spring3]サーブレットフィルタをSpringで管理する

この記事でも記載していますが、トランザクション境界を決定しなければ、mybatisならびにspringのトランザクション管理はうまく動きません。この例の場合、mybatisのDAOクラスを利用してデータの受け渡しを行うSpring管理下にあるServiceクラス経由で利用します。

具体的にいうと、

```
filter -> Service -> DAO(MybatisのSqlSessionを利用する)
```

ですね。

参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 前回の質問ではありがとうございました。
これが原因だったようです(^^;

ご指南のサイトどおりfilterにサービスを作成してみましたがインジェクションされずnullになりました。AuthenticateFilterの内容は記事に追加しておきました。

root-context.xml、servlet-context.xmlの使い分けがあまりよくわかっておらず、下記設定のみroot-context.xmlに記述しているのですが、これは良いのでしょうか？
<bean id="authenticateFilter" class="com.hatak.filter.AuthenticateFilter"></bean>

Comment: 状況から考えると、root-context.xmlもservlet-context.xmlもSpringによって正しく読み込まれているようですが、私の記事ではSpring MVCでの動作確認まで行っておりませんでした。root-context.xmlにかかず、servlet-context.xmlの方に統一したほうが良いとは思います（ただし動作確認しておりません）

Comment: authenticateFilterのbean登録はroot-context.xmlに記述しないとエラーが発生した。各種設定をroot-context.xmlで済ませることでインジェクションがnullの問題も解決できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 無事解決できて何よりです！お手数ですが本件を 解決済み にしていただけますか。